# Azure AKS cluster didn't created a storage account automatically

Tags: azure-aks

Azurefile PVC stuck in pending state because no storage account was automatically created by AKS.

I tried step by step documentation provided here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv
but without any sucess. I'm running azure-cli version 2.0.73.

Azurefile PVC creation should change to status Bound.

Comment: DO you not need to create the storage class before hand then assign it?

Comment: Can you show the yaml file that you create the sc and the pvc?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue, when you want to use the Azure File share as the persistent volumes. You need to follow two steps:

1. create the storage class
2. create the persistent volume claim

After these two things are created, then you can mount them to the pods. When creating, you need to pay attention to something:

- If you want to create the storage account automatically, you just need to add one or both the parameters `skuName` and `location`, no `storageAccount`.
- If you add the parameter `storageAccount`, then you must create the storage account yourself with the name you set.

You need to wait for munites, create the storage account also needs some time. Take a look at the [Storage Class for Azure File](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#azure-file).